# Работа с pug(jade)-шаблонами в проекте с помощью webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, jade, сборка, pug

Как можно преобразовать pug-файлы в html-шаблоны без их явного импортирования в точку входа?

Проект содержит шаблоны, стили, скрипты для каждого приложения, которые лежат в отдельном каталоге. Папка фронтенда:

```
├── frontend
│   ├── common
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── app1
│   ├── app2
│   ├── app3
│   ├── ...
│   └── webpack.config.js
```

Папка каждого приложения  содержит разное количество шаблонов:

```
├── app
│   ├── static
│   │   └── app
│   │       ├── css
│   │       └── js
│   └── templates
│       └── app
│           ├── app__tmp2.pug
│           ├── app.pug
│           ├── app__tmp1.pug
│           └── app__settings.pug
```

Соответственно их явное импортирование может быть неудобно.

В документации вебпака довольно мало написано о работе с препроцессорами шаблонов и для их работы необходимо явное импортирование. Мне же нужно, чтобы сборщик проходил рекурсивно все каталоги и оставлял преобразованный файл в месте исходника.

Попробовал решить проблему сам:

1. Использовал [pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader)
2. По совету [Умеренно Упоротая Утка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) из моего вопроса по [Сборка отдельных css и скриптов в общие файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605742/webpack-%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-css-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B) решил попробовать [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-all) для  обхода каталогов и включить шаблоны как точки входа (да, наверно, это выглядит странно).
   Часть моего конфига вебпака с лоадерами и точками входа:

   ```
   entry: {
     index: "./index.js",
     pug: glob.sync([path.join(__dirname + '/*.pug')])
   }
   ,
   output: {
     path: __dirname,
     filename: "[name].js"
   },
   module: {
    loaders: [{
     test: /\.pug/,
     loader: 'pug'
   }
   ```

Но при попытке сборки вебпак начинает бесконечно собирать проект.

Как правильно работать с шаблонами в проекте? Мой способ может работать? Где я допуская ошибки?

Comment: Ну то, что указывать шаблоны _точками_входа_ весьма стремно, это очевидно. Я с такой проблемой не сталкивался, один из вариантов решения - поискать какой-то лоадер, который умеет задавать глоб в импорте

Comment: Краткое гугление вот: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob, но звезд мало и сам не пробовал

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка вы меня снова выручаете. да, про шаблоны-точки входа сразу написал, что плохо выглядит.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка "не сталкивались с проблемой". вы работаете с шаблонами? или у вас виртуальный дом?

Comment: Еще вот это можно посмотреть: https://github.com/Aintaer/import-glob-loader. Но обратите внимание, все это штуки не оч популярные, может там все просто и тупо как часы, а может - и нет

Comment: ну да, у меня сейчас реакт. Когда я работал с бэкбоном и россыпью шаблонов, то шаблоны естественным образом соответствовали компонентам, и просто брать и глобать тоже не надо было

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка да, надо ставить реакт в ближайшую перспективу и читать. спасибо за ответы

Comment: Реакт хорош, но не одним реактом мир держится. На ближайшую перспективу и vue тоже ничотак,  и angular-2 при всей моей нелюбви к миру ангуляра. Будете выбирать - туда тоже посмотрите.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму я сделал по вашим советам, есть несколько непонятных ошибок, сможете подсказать?

Comment: Ага, ошибки вижу. их бы в отдельный вопрос вынести, чтобы не перегружать, а там можно на этот собраться.

Comment: По первому пункту - у вас преоладер import-glob парсит .pug файлы, а импорты вы видимо делаете в js-файлах?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608220/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-pugjade-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-webpack

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму да, импорт делаю в точке входа на js