# Ошибки при обработке pug(jade) шаблонов с помощью webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, jade, сборка, pug

По советам [Утки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%A3%D0%BC%D1%83) из вопроса ["Работа с pug(jade)-шаблонами в проекте с помощью webpack"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607812/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-pugjade-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-webpack) начал разбираться с pug-шаблонами:

1. Добавил [import-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob) в проект, однако, импорт вида `import "./**/*.pug"` (что допустимо согласно документации) выдает ошибку `Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./**/*.pug`. Добавил импорт с явным указанием пути `import "./common/templates/base.pug"`
2. Добавил в проект [pug-html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-html-loader) поправил конфиг вебпака

```js
var extractPug = new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].html");

...

module: {
      preloaders:[{
          test: /\.pug$/,
          loader: 'import-glob-loader'
      }],

      loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: [
        /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      ],
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }, {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          loader: extractPug.extract('pug-html')
      }, {
          test: /\.styl$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!stylus?resolve url')
      },]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css"),
        extractPug
    ]
```

3. Сборка прошла, однако файл шаблона появился в корне проекта с именем `main.html` и содержимым вида

```html
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);html {
  background: #fff;
  font: 1em Open Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #212121;
  height: 100%;
}

*все стили bundle.css*

*html-шаблон
```

Шаблон обратался корректно, но он содержит почему-то все стили, название отличное от исходного файла и располагается в корне проекта.

Как исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: Про первый пункт, повторюсь: Вы глоб-импорты делаете видимо в js файлах, а прелоадер парсит на наличие таких импортов - паг файлы. Попробуйте изменить параметр "test" в преоладере, и кормить ему - js файлы

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму изменил прелоадер на .js файлы, ошибка аналогична для импорта import "./**/*.pug". почему мы импорт-глоб используем именно в прелоадере, а не в лоадере вместе с бабелем, например

Comment: потому что в доке так написано))

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму чувствую, gulp придется задействовать

Comment: мб, и напороться на аналогичные грабли там) Можно собственно залезть в код этого лоадера и посмотреть где он валится, можно на гитхабе у автора спросить

Comment: ну, с импорт-глоб проблема условно решилась явным импортом. по прочим ошибками есть мысли?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50748/discussion-between----and-while1pass).