# Работа с pug(jade)-файлами в Gulp

Tags: gulp, jade, сборка, pug

Gulp не видит pug-шаблоны в проекте. [Пробовал обработать pug-файлы webpack'ом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607812/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-pugjade-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-webpack) и тоже получал ошибку в поиске файлов, по-видимому допускаю ошибку при задании регулярки поиска по шаблону.

Папка фронтенда в проекте:

```
├── frontend
│   ├── common
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── app1
│   ├── app2
│   ├── app3
│   ├── ...
│   └── gulpfile.js
```

Папка каждого приложения  содержит разное количество шаблонов:

```
├── app
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
│       └── app
│           ├── app__tmp2.pug
│           ├── app.pug
│           ├── app__tmp1.pug
│           └── app__settings.pug
```

Конфиг gulp предельно простой - обрабатываю шаблоны и кладу html-файлы рядом с исходником:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const pug = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('pug', function() {
  return gulp.src('frontend/**/*.pug', function(file){
      console.log(file)
  })
      .pipe(pug())
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./"))
});
```

Однако gulp не видит файлы по маске поиска `frontend/**/*.pug`
Результат консоли

```
(env)xxx@xxx:~/project/src/frontend$ gulp pug
   [20:39:38] Using gulpfile ~/project/mendeleev/src/frontend/gulpfile.js
   [20:39:38] Starting 'pug'...
   null
   [20:39:38] Finished 'pug' after 17 ms
```

Если я задам каталог поиска маской `**/*.pug`. Он обрабатывает файлы из первого каталога с шаблонами, а затем выдает ошибку:

```
Error: the "basedir" option is required to use includes and extends with "absolute" paths
```

Где допускаю ошибку? Возможно есть другие модули для работы с препроцессорами шаблонов?

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо было указать опцию `basedir` - директория `frontend`, конфиг следующий (поменял маску поиска и добавил исключение `!./node_modules/**`) :

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const pug = require('gulp-pug');


gulp.task('pug', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./**/*.pug', '!./node_modules/**'])
      .pipe(pug({
          basedir: __dirname
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./"))
});
```